# Instantiate an object through and Interface?

Tags: java

I'm trying to do a switch case which instantiate an object everytime the symbol on the Database is found, but I can't instantiate the objects because it can't find it.  was thinking if I had to go through an Interface or something ?

Don't hesitate asking me any questions ! Thank you guys

The "ViewPanel.java"

```
protected void paintComponent(final Graphics graphics) {

    for (x = 0; x < 21; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < 14; y++) {
            char symbol = '-'; // {call Selectlvl1(x,y)}; ?

            switch (symbol) {
            case '+':
                VBone bone = new VBone(x, y);
                Arimages.add(bone.Image());
                break;
            case '-':
                Hbone bone = new HBone(x, y);
                Arimages.add(bone.Image());
                //
                break;
            case '#':
                Corners corner = new Corners(x, y);
                Arimages.add(corner.Image());
                //
                break;
            case 'x':
                Purse purse = new Purse(x, y);
                Arimages.add(purse.Image());
                //
                break;
            case 'o':
                CrystalBall crystal = new CrystalBall(x, y);
                Arimages.add(crystal.Image());
                //
                break;
            case '$':
                DoorC door = new DoorC(x, y);
                Arimages.add(door.Image());
                //
                break;
            case '@':
                DoorO door = new DoorO(x, y);
                Arimages.add(door.Image());
                //
                break;
            default:
                Black black = new Black();
                Arimages.add(black);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    graphics.clearRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    for (Image img : Arimages) {

        graphics.drawImage(img, x * pixelNumbers, y * pixelNumbers, this);

        if (x == 21) {
            x = 0;
            y++;
        } else {
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

The "VBone.java" for instance ( All the object classes are the same ) :

```
public class VBone extends Background {
private int x;
private int y;

public VBone(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public void Image() throws IOException {
    BufferedImage vertical_bone = ImageIO.read(new File("src/main/resources/sprite/vertical_bone.png"));
}
```

}

The Hierarchy ( let's say ) :

> /view/ViewPanel.java
>
> /model/elements/VBone.java
>
> /contract/IModel.java /contract/IView.java

Comment: What do you mean when you say "you cannot instantiate the object because you cannot find it"? Do you get a ClassNotFoundException at runtime?

Comment: It just doesn't want to. I got the "VBone cannot be resolved to a type" Eclipse error.

Comment: In this case, you have to import the class using an import statement. You can do this automatically using Eclipse's quick fix mechanism. Put the cursor on the missing class and hit Ctrl+1. If Eclipse can find the class `VBone`, one option proposed by Eclipse will be to import the class.

Comment: Actually we have to work using Maven, so we can't import classes like that, that's the deal..